# Python List of dates between x and z (dd//mm/year)

Tags: python, date, datetime

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

d1 = date(1980, 1, 1)
d2 = date(2000, 1, 1)

delta = d2 - d1

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print d1 + td(days=i)
```

How would I make it so it displays it in this form: dd/mm/yy
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add this to your Print statement:

```
from datetime import date, timedelta as td

d1 = date(1980, 1, 1)
d2 = date(2000, 1, 1)

delta = d2 - d1

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print ((d1 + td(days=i)).strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
```

Output:
 ...

```
10/05/1996
11/05/1996
12/05/1996
13/05/1996
14/05/1996
15/05/1996
16/05/1996
17/05/1996
18/05/1996
19/05/1996
20/05/1996
21/05/1996
22/05/1996
23/05/1996
24/05/1996
25/05/1996
26/05/1996
27/05/1996
28/05/1996
29/05/1996
30/05/1996
31/05/1996
01/06/1996
02/06/1996
03/06/1996
04/06/1996
05/06/1996
06/06/1996
07/06/1996
08/06/1996
09/06/1996
10/06/1996
11/06/1996
12/06/1996
13/06/1996
14/06/1996
15/06/1996
16/06/1996
17/06/1996
18/06/1996
19/06/1996
20/06/1996
21/06/1996
22/06/1996
23/06/1996
24/06/1996
25/06/1996
26/06/1996
27/06/1996
28/06/1996
29/06/1996
30/06/1996
01/07/1996
02/07/1996
03/07/1996
04/07/1996
05/07/1996
06/07/1996
07/07/1996
08/07/1996
09/07/1996
10/07/1996
11/07/1996
12/07/1996
13/07/1996
14/07/1996
15/07/1996
16/07/1996
17/07/1996
18/07/1996
19/07/1996
20/07/1996
21/07/1996
22/07/1996
23/07/1996
24/07/1996
25/07/1996
26/07/1996
27/07/1996
28/07/1996
29/07/1996
30/07/1996
31/07/1996
01/08/1996
02/08/1996
03/08/1996
04/08/1996
05/08/1996
06/08/1996
07/08/1996
08/08/1996
09/08/1996
10/08/1996
11/08/1996
12/08/1996
13/08/1996
14/08/1996
15/08/1996
16/08/1996
17/08/1996
18/08/1996
19/08/1996
20/08/1996
21/08/1996
22/08/1996
23/08/1996
24/08/1996
25/08/1996
26/08/1996
27/08/1996
28/08/1996
29/08/1996
30/08/1996
31/08/1996
01/09/1996
02/09/1996
03/09/1996
04/09/1996
05/09/1996
06/09/1996
07/09/1996
08/09/1996
09/09/1996
10/09/1996
11/09/1996
12/09/1996
13/09/1996
14/09/1996
15/09/1996
16/09/1996
17/09/1996
18/09/1996
19/09/1996
20/09/1996
21/09/1996
22/09/1996
23/09/1996
24/09/1996
25/09/1996
26/09/1996
27/09/1996
28/09/1996
29/09/1996
30/09/1996
01/10/1996
02/10/1996
03/10/1996
04/10/1996
05/10/1996
06/10/1996
07/10/1996
08/10/1996
09/10/1996
10/10/1996
11/10/1996
12/10/1996
13/10/1996
14/10/1996
15/10/1996
16/10/1996
17/10/1996
18/10/1996
19/10/1996
20/10/1996
21/10/1996
22/10/1996
23/10/1996
24/10/1996
25/10/1996
26/10/1996
27/10/1996
28/10/1996
29/10/1996
30/10/1996
31/10/1996
01/11/1996
02/11/1996
03/11/1996
04/11/1996
05/11/1996
06/11/1996
07/11/1996
08/11/1996
09/11/1996
10/11/1996
11/11/1996
12/11/1996
13/11/1996
14/11/1996
15/11/1996
16/11/1996
17/11/1996
18/11/1996
19/11/1996
20/11/1996
21/11/1996
22/11/1996
23/11/1996
24/11/1996
25/11/1996
26/11/1996
27/11/1996
28/11/1996
29/11/1996
30/11/1996
01/12/1996
02/12/1996
03/12/1996
04/12/1996
05/12/1996
06/12/1996
07/12/1996
08/12/1996
09/12/1996
10/12/1996
11/12/1996
12/12/1996
13/12/1996
14/12/1996
15/12/1996
16/12/1996
17/12/1996
18/12/1996
19/12/1996
20/12/1996
21/12/1996
22/12/1996
23/12/1996
24/12/1996
25/12/1996
26/12/1996
27/12/1996
28/12/1996
29/12/1996
30/12/1996
31/12/1996
01/01/1997
02/01/1997
03/01/1997
04/01/1997
05/01/1997
06/01/1997
07/01/1997
08/01/1997
09/01/1997
10/01/1997
11/01/1997
12/01/1997
13/01/1997
14/01/1997
15/01/1997
16/01/1997
17/01/1997
18/01/1997
19/01/1997
20/01/1997
21/01/1997
22/01/1997
23/01/1997
24/01/1997
25/01/1997
26/01/1997
27/01/1997
28/01/1997
29/01/1997
30/01/1997
31/01/1997
01/02/1997
02/02/1997
03/02/1997
04/02/1997
05/02/1997
06/02/1997
07/02/1997
08/02/1997
09/02/1997
10/02/1997
11/02/1997
12/02/1997
13/02/1997
14/02/1997
15/02/1997
16/02/1997
17/02/1997
18/02/1997
19/02/1997
20/02/1997
21/02/1997
22/02/1997
23/02/1997
24/02/1997
25/02/1997
26/02/1997
27/02/1997
28/02/1997
01/03/1997
02/03/1997
03/03/1997
04/03/1997
05/03/1997
06/03/1997
07/03/1997
08/03/1997
09/03/1997
10/03/1997
11/03/1997
12/03/1997
13/03/1997
14/03/1997
15/03/1997
16/03/1997
17/03/1997
18/03/1997
19/03/1997
20/03/1997
21/03/1997
22/03/1997
23/03/1997
24/03/1997
25/03/1997
26/03/1997
27/03/1997
28/03/1997
29/03/1997
30/03/1997
31/03/1997
01/04/1997
02/04/1997
03/04/1997
04/04/1997
05/04/1997
06/04/1997
07/04/1997
08/04/1997
09/04/1997
10/04/1997
11/04/1997
12/04/1997
13/04/1997
14/04/1997
15/04/1997
16/04/1997
17/04/1997
18/04/1997
19/04/1997
20/04/1997
21/04/1997
22/04/1997
23/04/1997
24/04/1997
25/04/1997
26/04/1997
27/04/1997
28/04/1997
29/04/1997
30/04/1997
01/05/1997
02/05/1997
03/05/1997
04/05/1997
05/05/1997
06/05/1997
07/05/1997
08/05/1997
09/05/1997
10/05/1997
11/05/1997
12/05/1997
13/05/1997
14/05/1997
15/05/1997
16/05/1997
17/05/1997
18/05/1997
19/05/1997
20/05/1997
21/05/1997
22/05/1997
23/05/1997
24/05/1997
25/05/1997
26/05/1997
27/05/1997
28/05/1997
29/05/1997
30/05/1997
31/05/1997
01/06/1997
02/06/1997
03/06/1997
04/06/1997
05/06/1997
06/06/1997
07/06/1997
08/06/1997
09/06/1997
10/06/1997
11/06/1997
12/06/1997
13/06/1997
14/06/1997
15/06/1997
16/06/1997
17/06/1997
18/06/1997
19/06/1997
20/06/1997
21/06/1997
22/06/1997
23/06/1997
24/06/1997
25/06/1997
26/06/1997
27/06/1997
28/06/1997
29/06/1997
30/06/1997
01/07/1997
02/07/1997
03/07/1997
04/07/1997
05/07/1997
06/07/1997
07/07/1997
08/07/1997
09/07/1997
10/07/1997
11/07/1997
12/07/1997
13/07/1997
14/07/1997
15/07/1997
16/07/1997
17/07/1997
18/07/1997
19/07/1997
20/07/1997
21/07/1997
22/07/1997
23/07/1997
24/07/1997
25/07/1997
26/07/1997
27/07/1997
28/07/1997
29/07/1997
30/07/1997
31/07/1997
01/08/1997
02/08/1997
03/08/1997
04/08/1997
05/08/1997
06/08/1997
07/08/1997
08/08/1997
09/08/1997
10/08/1997
11/08/1997
12/08/1997
13/08/1997
14/08/1997
15/08/1997
16/08/1997
17/08/1997
18/08/1997
19/08/1997
20/08/1997
21/08/1997
22/08/1997
23/08/1997
24/08/1997
25/08/1997
26/08/1997
27/08/1997
28/08/1997
29/08/1997
30/08/1997
31/08/1997
01/09/1997
02/09/1997
03/09/1997
04/09/1997
05/09/1997
06/09/1997
07/09/1997
08/09/1997
09/09/1997
10/09/1997
11/09/1997
12/09/1997
13/09/1997
14/09/1997
15/09/1997
16/09/1997
17/09/1997
18/09/1997
19/09/1997
20/09/1997
21/09/1997
22/09/1997
23/09/1997
24/09/1997
25/09/1997
26/09/1997
27/09/1997
28/09/1997
29/09/1997
30/09/1997
01/10/1997
02/10/1997
03/10/1997
04/10/1997
05/10/1997
06/10/1997
07/10/1997
08/10/1997
09/10/1997
10/10/1997
11/10/1997
12/10/1997
13/10/1997
14/10/1997
15/10/1997
16/10/1997
17/10/1997
18/10/1997
19/10/1997
20/10/1997
21/10/1997
22/10/1997
23/10/1997
24/10/1997
25/10/1997
26/10/1997
27/10/1997
28/10/1997
29/10/1997
30/10/1997
31/10/1997
01/11/1997
02/11/1997
03/11/1997
04/11/1997
05/11/1997
06/11/1997
07/11/1997
08/11/1997
09/11/1997
10/11/1997
11/11/1997
12/11/1997
13/11/1997
14/11/1997
15/11/1997
16/11/1997
17/11/1997
18/11/1997
19/11/1997
20/11/1997
21/11/1997
22/11/1997
23/11/1997
24/11/1997
25/11/1997
26/11/1997
27/11/1997
28/11/1997
29/11/1997
30/11/1997
01/12/1997
02/12/1997
03/12/1997
04/12/1997
05/12/1997
06/12/1997
07/12/1997
08/12/1997
09/12/1997
10/12/1997
11/12/1997
12/12/1997
13/12/1997
14/12/1997
15/12/1997
16/12/1997
17/12/1997
18/12/1997
19/12/1997
20/12/1997
21/12/1997
22/12/1997
23/12/1997
24/12/1997
25/12/1997
26/12/1997
27/12/1997
28/12/1997
29/12/1997
30/12/1997
31/12/1997
01/01/1998
02/01/1998
03/01/1998
04/01/1998
05/01/1998
06/01/1998
07/01/1998
08/01/1998
09/01/1998
10/01/1998
11/01/1998
12/01/1998
13/01/1998
14/01/1998
15/01/1998
16/01/1998
17/01/1998
18/01/1998
19/01/1998
20/01/1998
21/01/1998
22/01/1998
23/01/1998
24/01/1998
25/01/1998
26/01/1998
27/01/1998
28/01/1998
29/01/1998
30/01/1998
31/01/1998
01/02/1998
02/02/1998
03/02/1998
04/02/1998
05/02/1998
06/02/1998
07/02/1998
08/02/1998
09/02/1998
10/02/1998
11/02/1998
12/02/1998
13/02/1998
14/02/1998
15/02/1998
16/02/1998
17/02/1998
18/02/1998
19/02/1998
20/02/1998
21/02/1998
22/02/1998
23/02/1998
24/02/1998
25/02/1998
26/02/1998
27/02/1998
28/02/1998
01/03/1998
02/03/1998
03/03/1998
04/03/1998
05/03/1998
06/03/1998
07/03/1998
08/03/1998
09/03/1998
10/03/1998
11/03/1998
12/03/1998
13/03/1998
14/03/1998
15/03/1998
16/03/1998
17/03/1998
18/03/1998
19/03/1998
20/03/1998
21/03/1998
22/03/1998
23/03/1998
24/03/1998
25/03/1998
26/03/1998
27/03/1998
28/03/1998
29/03/1998
30/03/1998
31/03/1998
01/04/1998
02/04/1998
03/04/1998
04/04/1998
05/04/1998
06/04/1998
07/04/1998
08/04/1998
09/04/1998
10/04/1998
11/04/1998
12/04/1998
13/04/1998
14/04/1998
15/04/1998
16/04/1998
17/04/1998
18/04/1998
19/04/1998
20/04/1998
21/04/1998
22/04/1998
23/04/1998
24/04/1998
25/04/1998
26/04/1998
27/04/1998
28/04/1998
29/04/1998
30/04/1998
01/05/1998
02/05/1998
03/05/1998
04/05/1998
05/05/1998
06/05/1998
07/05/1998
08/05/1998
09/05/1998
10/05/1998
11/05/1998
12/05/1998
13/05/1998
14/05/1998
15/05/1998
16/05/1998
17/05/1998
18/05/1998
19/05/1998
20/05/1998
21/05/1998
22/05/1998
23/05/1998
24/05/1998
25/05/1998
26/05/1998
27/05/1998
28/05/1998
29/05/1998
30/05/1998
31/05/1998
01/06/1998
02/06/1998
03/06/1998
04/06/1998
05/06/1998
06/06/1998
07/06/1998
08/06/1998
09/06/1998
10/06/1998
11/06/1998
12/06/1998
13/06/1998
14/06/1998
15/06/1998
16/06/1998
17/06/1998
18/06/1998
19/06/1998
20/06/1998
21/06/1998
22/06/1998
23/06/1998
24/06/1998
25/06/1998
26/06/1998
27/06/1998
28/06/1998
29/06/1998
30/06/1998
01/07/1998
02/07/1998
03/07/1998
04/07/1998
05/07/1998
06/07/1998
07/07/1998
08/07/1998
09/07/1998
10/07/1998
11/07/1998
12/07/1998
13/07/1998
14/07/1998
15/07/1998
16/07/1998
17/07/1998
18/07/1998
19/07/1998
20/07/1998
21/07/1998
22/07/1998
23/07/1998
24/07/1998
25/07/1998
26/07/1998
27/07/1998
28/07/1998
29/07/1998
30/07/1998
31/07/1998
01/08/1998
02/08/1998
03/08/1998
04/08/1998
05/08/1998
06/08/1998
07/08/1998
08/08/1998
09/08/1998
10/08/1998
11/08/1998
12/08/1998
13/08/1998
14/08/1998
15/08/1998
16/08/1998
17/08/1998
18/08/1998
19/08/1998
20/08/1998
21/08/1998
22/08/1998
23/08/1998
24/08/1998
25/08/1998
26/08/1998
27/08/1998
28/08/1998
29/08/1998
30/08/1998
31/08/1998
01/09/1998
02/09/1998
03/09/1998
04/09/1998
05/09/1998
06/09/1998
07/09/1998
08/09/1998
09/09/1998
10/09/1998
11/09/1998
12/09/1998
13/09/1998
14/09/1998
15/09/1998
16/09/1998
17/09/1998
18/09/1998
19/09/1998
20/09/1998
21/09/1998
22/09/1998
23/09/1998
24/09/1998
25/09/1998
26/09/1998
27/09/1998
28/09/1998
29/09/1998
30/09/1998
01/10/1998
02/10/1998
03/10/1998
04/10/1998
05/10/1998
06/10/1998
07/10/1998
08/10/1998
09/10/1998
10/10/1998
11/10/1998
12/10/1998
13/10/1998
14/10/1998
15/10/1998
16/10/1998
17/10/1998
18/10/1998
19/10/1998
20/10/1998
21/10/1998
22/10/1998
23/10/1998
24/10/1998
25/10/1998
26/10/1998
27/10/1998
28/10/1998
29/10/1998
30/10/1998
31/10/1998
01/11/1998
02/11/1998
03/11/1998
04/11/1998
05/11/1998
06/11/1998
07/11/1998
08/11/1998
09/11/1998
10/11/1998
11/11/1998
12/11/1998
13/11/1998
14/11/1998
15/11/1998
16/11/1998
17/11/1998
18/11/1998
19/11/1998
20/11/1998
21/11/1998
22/11/1998
23/11/1998
24/11/1998
25/11/1998
26/11/1998
27/11/1998
28/11/1998
29/11/1998
30/11/1998
01/12/1998
02/12/1998
03/12/1998
04/12/1998
05/12/1998
06/12/1998
07/12/1998
08/12/1998
09/12/1998
10/12/1998
11/12/1998
12/12/1998
13/12/1998
14/12/1998
15/12/1998
16/12/1998
17/12/1998
18/12/1998
19/12/1998
20/12/1998
21/12/1998
22/12/1998
23/12/1998
24/12/1998
25/12/1998
26/12/1998
27/12/1998
28/12/1998
29/12/1998
30/12/1998
31/12/1998
01/01/1999
02/01/1999
03/01/1999
04/01/1999
05/01/1999
06/01/1999
07/01/1999
08/01/1999
09/01/1999
10/01/1999
11/01/1999
12/01/1999
13/01/1999
14/01/1999
15/01/1999
16/01/1999
17/01/1999
18/01/1999
19/01/1999
20/01/1999
21/01/1999
22/01/1999
23/01/1999
24/01/1999
25/01/1999
26/01/1999
27/01/1999
28/01/1999
29/01/1999
30/01/1999
31/01/1999
01/02/1999
02/02/1999
03/02/1999
04/02/1999
05/02/1999
06/02/1999
07/02/1999
08/02/1999
09/02/1999
10/02/1999
11/02/1999
12/02/1999
13/02/1999
14/02/1999
15/02/1999
16/02/1999
17/02/1999
18/02/1999
19/02/1999
20/02/1999
21/02/1999
22/02/1999
23/02/1999
24/02/1999
25/02/1999
26/02/1999
27/02/1999
28/02/1999
01/03/1999
02/03/1999
03/03/1999
04/03/1999
05/03/1999
06/03/1999
07/03/1999
08/03/1999
09/03/1999
10/03/1999
11/03/1999
12/03/1999
13/03/1999
14/03/1999
15/03/1999
16/03/1999
17/03/1999
18/03/1999
19/03/1999
20/03/1999
21/03/1999
22/03/1999
23/03/1999
24/03/1999
25/03/1999
26/03/1999
27/03/1999
28/03/1999
29/03/1999
30/03/1999
31/03/1999
01/04/1999
02/04/1999
03/04/1999
04/04/1999
05/04/1999
06/04/1999
07/04/1999
08/04/1999
09/04/1999
10/04/1999
11/04/1999
12/04/1999
13/04/1999
14/04/1999
15/04/1999
16/04/1999
17/04/1999
18/04/1999
19/04/1999
20/04/1999
21/04/1999
22/04/1999
23/04/1999
24/04/1999
25/04/1999
26/04/1999
27/04/1999
28/04/1999
29/04/1999
30/04/1999
01/05/1999
02/05/1999
03/05/1999
04/05/1999
05/05/1999
06/05/1999
07/05/1999
08/05/1999
09/05/1999
10/05/1999
11/05/1999
12/05/1999
13/05/1999
14/05/1999
15/05/1999
16/05/1999
17/05/1999
18/05/1999
19/05/1999
20/05/1999
21/05/1999
22/05/1999
23/05/1999
24/05/1999
25/05/1999
26/05/1999
27/05/1999
28/05/1999
29/05/1999
30/05/1999
31/05/1999
01/06/1999
02/06/1999
03/06/1999
04/06/1999
05/06/1999
06/06/1999
07/06/1999
08/06/1999
09/06/1999
10/06/1999
11/06/1999
12/06/1999
13/06/1999
14/06/1999
15/06/1999
16/06/1999
17/06/1999
18/06/1999
19/06/1999
20/06/1999
21/06/1999
22/06/1999
23/06/1999
24/06/1999
25/06/1999
26/06/1999
27/06/1999
28/06/1999
29/06/1999
30/06/1999
01/07/1999
02/07/1999
03/07/1999
04/07/1999
05/07/1999
06/07/1999
07/07/1999
08/07/1999
09/07/1999
10/07/1999
11/07/1999
12/07/1999
13/07/1999
14/07/1999
15/07/1999
16/07/1999
17/07/1999
18/07/1999
19/07/1999
20/07/1999
21/07/1999
22/07/1999
23/07/1999
24/07/1999
25/07/1999
26/07/1999
27/07/1999
28/07/1999
29/07/1999
30/07/1999
31/07/1999
01/08/1999
02/08/1999
03/08/1999
04/08/1999
05/08/1999
06/08/1999
07/08/1999
08/08/1999
09/08/1999
10/08/1999
11/08/1999
12/08/1999
13/08/1999
14/08/1999
15/08/1999
16/08/1999
17/08/1999
18/08/1999
19/08/1999
20/08/1999
21/08/1999
22/08/1999
23/08/1999
24/08/1999
25/08/1999
26/08/1999
27/08/1999
28/08/1999
29/08/1999
30/08/1999
31/08/1999
01/09/1999
02/09/1999
03/09/1999
04/09/1999
05/09/1999
06/09/1999
07/09/1999
08/09/1999
09/09/1999
10/09/1999
11/09/1999
12/09/1999
13/09/1999
14/09/1999
15/09/1999
16/09/1999
17/09/1999
18/09/1999
19/09/1999
20/09/1999
21/09/1999
22/09/1999
23/09/1999
24/09/1999
25/09/1999
26/09/1999
27/09/1999
28/09/1999
29/09/1999
30/09/1999
01/10/1999
02/10/1999
03/10/1999
04/10/1999
05/10/1999
06/10/1999
07/10/1999
08/10/1999
09/10/1999
10/10/1999
11/10/1999
12/10/1999
13/10/1999
14/10/1999
15/10/1999
16/10/1999
17/10/1999
18/10/1999
19/10/1999
20/10/1999
21/10/1999
22/10/1999
23/10/1999
24/10/1999
25/10/1999
26/10/1999
27/10/1999
28/10/1999
29/10/1999
30/10/1999
31/10/1999
01/11/1999
02/11/1999
03/11/1999
04/11/1999
05/11/1999
06/11/1999
07/11/1999
08/11/1999
09/11/1999
10/11/1999
11/11/1999
12/11/1999
13/11/1999
14/11/1999
15/11/1999
16/11/1999
17/11/1999
18/11/1999
19/11/1999
20/11/1999
21/11/1999
22/11/1999
23/11/1999
24/11/1999
25/11/1999
26/11/1999
27/11/1999
28/11/1999
29/11/1999
30/11/1999
01/12/1999
02/12/1999
03/12/1999
04/12/1999
05/12/1999
06/12/1999
07/12/1999
08/12/1999
09/12/1999
10/12/1999
11/12/1999
12/12/1999
13/12/1999
14/12/1999
15/12/1999
16/12/1999
17/12/1999
18/12/1999
19/12/1999
20/12/1999
21/12/1999
22/12/1999
23/12/1999
24/12/1999
25/12/1999
26/12/1999
27/12/1999
28/12/1999
29/12/1999
30/12/1999
31/12/1999
01/01/2000
```

Comment: Thnk you very much. Both answers very useful. I needed a captical Y not a y.

Comment: I know as 2000 on wards can look confusing if only 00.And welcome to Stack Overflow! If this helped you, you can tell the community so by voting the answer! :)

Comment: Thank you for the welcome. Both solutions worked but I approved yours since gave an example of output too. Both did same thing so thank you both

Comment: Much appreciated! Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

Use [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
print your_date.strftime("%d/%m/%y")
```

Comment: What about for the full year  like 1990? It only shows 90 but other than that its fine

Comment: @smye, `yy` in the format normally means '_year without century as a zero-padded decimal number_'. Have you checked the link I've given in my answer?

Comment: Thank you for this, didn't realise it was hyperlinked ;P